# Postgres error: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target

Tags: postgresql

I have an old project that I'm trying to get back into, but I can't enter postgres. Running `sudo -u postgres psql` gives me:

```
Error: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. 
Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
```

I'm wondering if this might be because I upgraded postgres to version 9.4 a few months back. This is my output for `dpkg --get-selections |grep postgres`:

```
postgresql                          install
postgresql-9.3                      install
postgresql-9.4                      install
postgresql-client-9.3               install
postgresql-client-9.4               install
postgresql-client-common            install
postgresql-common                   install
postgresql-contrib                  install
postgresql-contrib-9.3              install
postgresql-contrib-9.4              install
postgresql-server-dev-9.3           install
```

These are my current clusters from `pg_lsclusters`:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.4 apps    5434 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/apps /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-apps.log

9.4 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
```

What can I do to be able to access postgres again? Googling hasn't been much help.

Comment: **Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.**. So, when you read the documentation....

Comment: I also started getting the same warning because I went from only having the postgres-10 cluster installed to having the postgres-10 and postgres-11 clusters installed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As none of your clusters listens on the default port `5432`, `psql` (which is in fact a link to `pg_wrapper`) doesn't know which one should be the "default".

You may use `psql --cluster 9.4/apps [other arguments]` to access the first cluster and `psql --cluster 9.4/main [other arguments]` for the second one.

Or alternatively define a `$PGCLUSTER` environment variable to `9.4/apps` or `9.4/main`

These come from rules #2 and #4 (out of 8) of [pg_wrapper manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html).

Comment: or `locate postgresql.conf` and change the port to 5432 in the file of the preferred version

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care what your default cluster is, and just want things to work like they did before, just specify the port you want to connect to with

```
psql -p 5432
```

and postgres won't try to be clever for you and use a "cluster", whatever that is.

Answer (score 5):

Just set PGCLUSTER

```
export PGCLUSTER=9.4/main
```